# How to create a trigger to populate a table in database based on saved data in another table from laravel controller

Tags: sql, database, laravel, api, model-view-controller

I am creating an API with Laravel where I am trying to populate a table in a database based on saved data in another table in the database. So after **table 1** data is saved, it should trigger for **table 2** data to be also saved.

Here is the code for Controller of **table 1**

```
 public function create(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|unique:users',
            'code' => 'required'
        ]);

            Auth::user();
            $user = new User();
            $user->inputed_code = $request->inputed_code;
            $user->code = $request->code;
            $user->save();

            return response([
                    'success' => true,
                    'message' => 'Data has been saved!!',
                    'data' => $user,
                ], Response::HTTP_OK);
     }
```

Here is the Controller for **table 2** which I want to populate based on result from **table 1** through a trigger effect.

```
public function reward(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $reward = new Reward();
        $reward->user_id = DB::table('users')->get(id)
        $reward->points = $request->referral_reward;
        $reward->save();
        $user = $request->only('user_id');
        $reward = Reward::where('user_id', '=', $user)->update([
            'referral_reward' => 5
            ]);
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'You have been awarded 5 points',
            'data' => $reward,
        ], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

Here are the API routes

```
Route::post('applycode', 'UserController@create');
Route::post('reward', 'RewardController@reward');
```

Please what am I doing wrong and is there is better way to approach this is give the same results.

Thank you

Comment: you can create `created` hook in table 1 so when table 1 data is create you can trigger table 2 creation

Answer (score 1):

I understand that based on a saved `User` model you want to save something in your `rewards` table.

You could use [*Eloquent events*](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events). Register an event in your `User` model like this:

```php
class User extends Model {

// ... other stuff

  protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'saved' => UserSaved::class,
  ];

}
```

Then you need to create your events file by running `php artisan make:event UserSaved`, which creates a file `app/Events/UserSaved.php`. In this files `__construct` method you receive the affected model as parameter.

```php
public function __construct(User $user)
{
  // ... do sth
}
```

Then you need event listeners, [see the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events), to consume the event

> After defining and mapping your Eloquent events, you may use event listeners to handle the events.

Then inside the listener you can do all the logic you want to apply to your `Rewards` model.